# search between two dates using MYSQL / SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which is clientbike

SELECT stime,etime FROM clientbike

```
    stime       |  etime 
    --------------------------
    2016-04-01  |  2016-04-30
```

if anybody search stime = 2016-04-05  &  etime =  2016-04-07

result Found

```
    2 Days...
```

Can someone explain how to do using sql / mysql ?

Thnaks

Comment: any idea about this question...

Comment: What datatype are `stime` and `etime`?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to count the number of days from `2016-04-05` to `2016-04-07`? That would be 3 in my opinion (the 5th, the 6th, the 7th). Could you please clarify your question? Does your table contain only one row?

Comment: The specification is woefully incomplete. Likely, the query needs to handle more cases than one row in clientbike, with values of stime and etime  other than '2016-04-01' and '2016-04-30', and with search parameters other than '2016-04-05' and '2016-04-07'. This isn't really a sql/mysql problem, as much as it is a problem with developing a specification. We can fling SQL at the problem, but unless we understand what result is to be returned for other conditions, it's not possible to even write test cases, much less a SQL statement. (I nominate this question for the "WTF?" award of the week.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to just copy below query and execute in mysql, then you can see this query is returning number of count entry from staring date to end date.

You can achieve this in two way,

**Option 1**

```
    SET @FromDate := '2016-04-1'  
    SET @ToDate := '2016-04-30' 

    SELECT COUNT(* ) FROM clientbike
    WHERE stime >= @FromDate AND etime <= @ToDate
```

This is covering all date range scenario like selected `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` both are within start and end column in table.

**Option 2**

```
     SET @FromDate := '2016-04-1'  
     SET @ToDate := '2016-04-30' 
     SELECT count(*) FROM clientbike WHERE stime BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND etime BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

Comment: `DECLARE @FromDate DATE = '2016-04-1'` will not work in MySQL, Try `SET @FromDate := '2016-04-1'` instead.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel Thanks buddy, I modified.

Comment: This will not work. Using the example table the OP gave, both queries would return `1` since you are counting the number of records in `clientbike`, but the number of days.

Comment: Also, this will not cover the cases when one or both of the searched dates are outside `stime` and `etime`. Switch `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` , flip the equality operators, and you will get all records where the dates overlap.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting the number of overlapping days, with the `EndDate` being exclusive. If that is correct then start with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM clientbike
WHERE stime <= @ToDate
    AND etime >= @FromDate;
```

This query will return any records from `clientbike` that overlap the searched dates. Structuring the `WHERE` clause this way checks for start overhang, end overhang, `@ToDate` and `@FromDate` between `sdate` and `edate`, and `sdate` and `edate` being between `@ToDate` and `@FromDate`.

Next we need to modify the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT GREATEST(stime, @FromDate) AS startDate,
    LEAST(etime, @ToDate) AS endDate
FROM clientbike
WHERE stime <= @ToDate
    AND etime >= @FromDate;
```

The point of `GREATEST` and `LEAST` is to ensure that we only look at the dates that actually overlap. EX: if `stime = '2016-04-15'` and `@FromDate = '2016-04-22'`, then `GREATEST(stime, @FromDate) = '2016-04-22'`. We will then use these two fields to calculate the date difference between `startDate` and `endDate`:

```
SELECT GREATEST(stime, @FromDate) AS startDate,
    LEAST(etime, @ToDate) AS endDate, 
    DATEDIFF(LEAST(etime, @ToDate), GREATEST(stime, @FromDate)) as overlap
FROM clientbike
WHERE stime <= @ToDate
    AND etime >= @FromDate;
```

The only part of the `SELECT` that matters is the `DATEDIFF()` function, so the preceding two fields can be removed. I just left them in so you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Given the one case in the specification, it's fairly straightforward. What's missing from the specification is examples of stime and/or etime values that are equal, or are entirely or partially outside the clientbike range. Or etime values that are equal to stime. For both search parameters and for column values. (I strongly suspect there is *more* to the specification than just the one case.)

As a starting point, here's an example that happens to "work" for the case in the specification.  This returns a row for *every* row in clientbike.

setup

```
CREATE TABLE clientbike
( id      BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, stime   DATE NOT NULL 
, etime   DATE NOT NULL
); 

INSERT INTO clientbike (stime,etime) VALUES 
 ('2016-04-01','2016-04-30')
, ('2016-05-01','2016-05-30') ;
```

example query

```
SELECT b.id
     , IF(q.etime >= b.stime AND q.stime < b.etime, DATEDIFF(q.etime,q.stime), 0) AS days
  FROM clientbike b
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT '2016-04-05' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS stime
              , '2016-04-07' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS etime
       ) q
 ORDER BY b.id
```

NOTE: The "search" values are supplied in the inline view q.

returns

```
  id  days
----  ----
   1     2
   2     0
```

---

As a ridiculous example of another query that would also satisfy the given specification but would be virtually impossible to extend to other cases...

```
SELECT b.id
     , IF(    b.stime = '2016-04-01'
          AND b.etime = '2016-04-30'
          AND q.stime = '2016-04-05'
          AND q.etime = '2016-04-07'
       , '2 Days...'
       , ''
       ) AS result
    FROM clientbike b     
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT '2016-04-05' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS stime
              , '2016-04-07' + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS etime
       ) q
```

returns

```
  id  result  
----  ---------
   1  2 Days...  
   2
```